# FFMPEG's FLAC Compression Levels & Defaults Settings

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, flac, lossless

I have searched for the documentation on this but found no information.

I'm using the latest FFMPEG nightly build in Windows 10 Insider Build (also latest) 64 Bit.

I need to know how to define the compression level of FLAC files.

Also, by default does FFMPEG change anything in the FLAC files.
Here's an example: Let's say I have an unaltered source FLAC file that I convert to FLAC again inside FFMPEG what will change by default when it processes it? Is there any way to make sure FFMPEG does not alter the original quality? I'm aware that FLAC is lossless but I thought it might change the bit depth or bit rate.

Answer (score 8):

There's a generic option that is picked up by the FLAC encoder

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -compression_level 8 out.flac
```

Vales go from 0 to 12. Default is 5.

The FLAC encoder works with either 16 or 32 bit samples. Other sizes will be stored as one of these two options.

Comment: Okay so I need to add " -compression_level 12" to this line of code I already have to convert files to flac "for %%a in ("*.*") do (ffmpeg -i "%%a" "%%~na.flac")" how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Command in brackets would be `ffmpeg -i "%%a" -compression_level 12 "%%~na.flac"`

Comment: I've tried running ffmpeg -i "%%a" -compression_level 12 "%%~na.flac" but even after modifying it it always comes back with this error %a: No such file or directory

Comment: Remove the 2nd % from the output name.

Comment: Okay now that causes this error: ~na.flac: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you executing this code from command line or in batch file?

Comment: It's all within a batch file, but executing in the cmd will have the same effect. It's basically the same either way.

Comment: It does not encode 32 bit samples though. There is patch on the mailing list you could apply to fix that, but there is a bug that affects that and .wv files for 32 bit.